# Liquibase applies patches after Camel starts, leading to an error

Tags: apache-camel, liquibase, weld

I'm struggling to get Liquibase and Camel to work seamlessly.

It happens that Camel initiates its routes before Liquibase applies its patches, leading to an error if the former has to access a table that is not in the database yet.

As a workaround, I've put in a delayed thread the start of the routes. It works, but not in every case: e.g. Weld does not propagate context in new threads, so I cannot do anything complicated in them.

Is there a way to delay Camel start or anticipate the time Liquibase applies its patches?

Comment: Which kind of architecture framework do you use for the application?

Comment: Simply Java EE with Weld CDI implementation, running in Wildfly.

Answer (score 0):

Set autoStartup=false for your camel routes and start the routes once after liquibase patches up the database. You may use a timer or the value of LOCKED flag set on liquibase generated table 'databasechangeloglock' to check if liquibase is patching or not based on your use case.